# Can you enable automatic updates in the guest account?

Tags: updates

I have set the update settings to automatically install the security updates; but are they supposed to get installed when logged in to the guest session too?

Also, I wonder if it is possible to set the other updates to automatic as well?

Answer (score 1):

When you update your computer it is applied system-wide in most cases. So, yes the guest will also have those updates.

In addition, by default any saved data or changed settings will be removed/reset at logout from guest session. Each guest session starts with a fresh environment, unaffected by what previous guests did.

Have a look at the Ubuntuwiki pages [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)